# Why data-centric is bad?

Tags: middleware

On the answers of the posted question:
"[What is the difference between data-centric and object-oriented application models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346995/what-is-the-difference-between-data-centric-and-object-oriented-application-mode)" I read:

> when you were mentioning the "message passing" example, you said one
>   way to implement it is the data-centric (although you consider it a
>   bad way).

Why data-centric is a bad way? Knowing that the data-centric approach released by RTI looks to be an interesting approach for real-time distributed applications.

Is the alternative message-centric? application-centric? or?

Comment: "The data centric approach released by RTI" - you are referring to the OMG DDS standard which has many implementations.

Answer (score 1):

A data-centric design has classes with no meaningful methods. These classes just hold data. This isn't really an appropriate use of something that can house functionality as well as properties. Data-Centric also localizes all of it's functionality in a few classes, that have to do all the work.

In a busy network, if we're constantly referencing the same objects to do all of the work, we're going to quickly develop queues of tasks that would be dealt with much quicker if the various responsibilities were split up amongst several classes.

Also, this doesn't conform to design principles like [Dijksta's Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), which are considered to be good practice.

Comment: but data-centric is the act to write and read from a database, while it can be implemented over an underlay protocol like the publish the subscribe

Comment: It really depends I guess. Usually Data Centric does also mean something different for me. In a Data Centric approach you often find the principle of Objects being not utilizable. Its like writing an Object class for every line in a spread sheet or just write a Object representing the spread sheet.

Look it form this way: Data Centric means Data means collection and therefore means repositiory resulting in the Domain Driven Design of Evens. So Data Centric is best suited by building Repositories around them.

Comment: @christopher I have to respectfully disagree. Data centricity does not enforce a level of granularity. A user is free to split up functionality into any number of classes that he/she desires. Also, data centric designs can most certainly contain methods. The difference however is that methods here are for convenience while data (members) represents the external interface of a class.

Comment: Also, please note that in a data centric class, side effects are encapsulated by data instead of methods. An example: I have an OOP class 'Car'. This class would have a method move(x,y), which would trigger the car to move to a certain position (a side effect). The data centric version of this class would have me update the members x&y (atomically), which would trigger the car to start moving.

Answer (score 0):

Objects contain both data and methods as to promote a more "natural" RL-compliant way of thinking about programming, you don't just have a "dosier" class which hold information, that dossier class also has methods for accessing that data like `readPage(int pageNr)`.

To forgo writing methods is certainly possible and advisable in some corner cases, for example to not have to use reflection I declared a DataTransferObject, but most of the time it is a waste of potential.

Comment: but does data-centric architecture responsibility to allow methods to read from this data? (like providing the read page functionality)

Comment: sorry I think you're missing the verb: does data centric architecture "have" the responsibility/"imply" the responsibility /"demand" the responsibility? the answer is no by definition but that's the whole point the architecture is self limiting I can't recommend it but for very specific cases.

Comment: but can u please explain what is the link between data-centric and the message oriented middleware? so can i say that data-centric is actually under the ambrella of MOM?